# Does Cortex m3 parse a firmware code from -code D-code bus?

Tags: cortex-m, cortex-m3

I'm trying to understand the reason of I-code and D-code bus in Cortex M3 and how simple arbiter into single slave(Flash/ROM/RAM) can make an improvement performance of device.
(https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/system/f/soc-design-forum/2045/arm-cortex-icode-dcode-system-buses/6884#6884)

In the Cortex M3 TRM document, Cortex M3 core consists with a Bus matrix by 3 bus of I,D and S.

As far as I know, generally, these 3 bus connect to a simple AHB bus(CODE AHBM) with memories like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVp8L.jpg

Why I-code and D-code bus separated in Cortex M3? and how single arbiter such as AHB bus (CODE AHBM) will help for performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Why I-code and D-code bus separated in Cortex M3"

The micro controller can fetch data from the D-bus during the execution of an instruction coming from the I-bus or while the pipeline is fetching another instruction from the I-bus.

Yes, just as you pointed that out, this architecture speeds up code execution.

Comment: I'm confused that the downloaded firmware code will be saved at the one memory but in the memory there is no any instruction what data involved in I-bus or D-bus. so How does I-Bus and D-Bus work for one memory?  As I know, I and D bus see the same address.  Who make the decision which bus need to work?

Comment: "Yes, just as you pointed that out, this architecture speeds up code execution." would you please let me know more detail about how does that kind of architecture would speed up code execution?

Comment: The arbiter decides which bus has access to the memory - consider what happens in an instruction stream - i bus only does reads, d bus does read/writes. For a microcontroller with internal flash, the i bus is mainly going to be reading from flash. Flash is rarely written. The d bus will normally talk to ram and peripherals. Having an i and d bus means you can add caching without much hassle and tailor the bus strategies to suit.also note that d accesses will probably be less than i reads as most of the opcodes work on registers -  RISC architecture.

Comment: @Kartman Thanks,  How does arbiter know which bus need to access the memory?

Comment: There's a Look-ahead mechanism that handles that.

Comment: The buses have control signals. Like ‘i wanna do a read or I wanna do a write’. The arbiter hears this, determines who should go first, performs the bus cycle then tells the i or d bus, ‘I’ve finished’. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @Kartman  Thanks again. as your said "I bus only does read,  D bus does read/write. and arbiter decide which bus have to be first work by their " https://imgur.com/YrVY671 But I'm some confused that arbiter just decide by central multiplexor interconnection scheme...I mean that the arbiter determines which master has its address and control signals routed to all of the slaves. it's deterministic by master and slave.

Comment: @Carter. I could not make sense of what you wrote. I think your making a very simple mechanism very complicated. There is no magic. If you want to understand the operation down to gate level, you’ve jumped way ahead and missed some fundamentals.

Comment: @Kartman Actually, I was thinking the I-Bus and D-Bus works by Firmware Code context(Firmware code constructed by I context(such as instruction commands) and D context( such as Data). But As your said, it does not any relationship between Firmware code context and Bus choice between I and D

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the predecessor to the M3 you can see the disadvantage of using a unified cache. On the ARM7 processors released in the early 90s, a single cache was used for both instructions and data to reduce costs. Because the cache is shared, instruction and data accesses must alternate. As a result, the fetch stage of the processor must stall anytime a previous instruction accesses memory.

Programming these processors was quite annoying. Because you could not access data and instruction memory at the same time, efficient execution required the used of very awkward load multiple and store multiple instructions to queue up multiple memory accesses with a single instruction load. Otherwise simple things like looping over an array to implement a filter could run at half speed as every load and every store blocked fetching the next CPU instruction.

While using separate I and D caches increases transistor counts, it is ultimately much more efficient and had the benefit of allowing ARM to depreciate the (complex to implement) load multiple and store multiple instructions, allowing simplification of the cores themselves.  As for how the CPU knows which cache to use, it is quite simple.  A memory access originating form the fetch stage of the pipeline checks the I-cache, and on miss, loads a cache line into the I-cache.  A  memory access originating from the memory access stage of the pipeline checks the D-cache and on miss, loads a cache line into the D-cache.  Thus the two types of access are naturally sorted into their respective caches.